# Convert to a new interval in C programming

Tags: c, intervals

I am working on a project where I am controlling the motor of a boat(a model). I have a method that gives out values from zero to 1000 that is used to regulate the forward speed of the boat, but my motor only moves forward with values from 80 to 160. My question is,
is it possible to somehow convert this large interval to the smaller one? So that zero equals 80, 1000 equals 160, and all the values in between are evenly distributed (1 equals 80.08, 2 equals 80.16 etc.) ? Any tips on a good way to do this?

I am writing the code in C.

Comment: calculate value * 80 / 1000 + 80

Comment: What have you tried? SO questions of this type need to include a bit of code to show what you actually want.

Comment: How about some simple math? And are you sure that your throttle is set by a float and not an integer? If it is an integer you cannot use decimals.

Comment: linearity : y = 80 + (160/1000)*(x-80)

Comment: @georgesl `160/1000` will give you `0` as it is an integer division.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Answer (score 2):

High school algebra to the rescue!

```
y = mx + b
```

Your slope `m` is the change in the new variable relative to a change in the old, so

```
m = (160-80)/(1000-0) = 0.08
```

Your y-intercept, `b`, is the new value at the point where the old value is zero:

```
y = 80 at x = 0
```

So,

```
y = 0.08 x + 80
```

Or in C:

```
int oldValue;
float newValue;

oldValue = 500;
newValue = 0.08*(float)oldValue + 80.0

// newValue is 120.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a value in the interval [0, 1000]. You want to convert that value to be in the interval [80, 160].

If you divide the value by 1000, you have a value in the interval [0, 1]. And if you multiply it by the size of the new interval (160 - 80), you have a value between [0, 80]. Now you add an offset of 80 in order to get the value in the interval [80, 160].

Mathematically, this is equal to:

```
value / 1000 * (160 - 80) + 80
```

In C:

```
double newvalue = value / 1000.0 * (160 - 80) + 80;
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested code, comments should explain all...

```
double scaleValue(double value, 
                  double originalMin, double originalMax, 
                  double newMin, double newMax)
{
    // scale original value to range 0...1
    double normalizedValue = (originalMax - originalMin) / (value - originalMin);

    // optional, outside question scope, change shape of the curve, for example:
    // normalizedValue = normalizedValue * normalizedValue

    // calculate position in new scale
    double scaledNormalizedValue = (newMax - newMin) * normalizedValue;

    // return new value in new range
    return scaledNormalizedValue + newMin;
}
```

Example use for question values:

```
motorValue = scaleValue(speedValue, 0, 1000, 80, 160);
```